# How to use AWS S3 for npm registry (nodeJs AWS Lambda)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, npm, aws-lambda

I configure multi repository in my `.npmrc` file using `@scope`:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
@my-npm-s3:registry=https://my-npm-registry.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

I add my @scope to my personal dependancy in my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "my-config",
  "dependencies": {
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "@my-npm-s3/my-common": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

I create delivery `my-common-1.0.0.tgz` file with `npm pack`

```
{
  "name": "my-common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "me"
}
```

I create S3 bucket named `my-npm-registry` and I create a folder named `@my-npm-s3` and I add `my-common-1.0.0.tgz` file in this folder

I run `npm install` on other NodeJs AWS Lambda (`my-config`) and I have this error:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://my-npm-registry.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/@my-npm-s3%2fmy-common
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
npm ERR! 403
npm ERR! 403 It was specified as a dependency of 'my-config'
npm ERR! 403
```

I can see that my GET do not contains `1.0.0` version!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

now AWS have new sercvice (`codeartifact`), so I do not use S3.

step 1: Update aws cli

step 2: Create aws codeartifact

- Repository name (my-repo)
- Domain (my-domain)

step 3: Edit my module

```
{
  "name": "@my-npm/my-common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run co:login",
    "co:login": "aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository my-repo --domain my-domain --domain-owner <123456789> --profile <me>",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "me"
}
```

step 5 : run `npm publish`

**Now your module is on AWS codeartifact**

use this module:

step 1: Edit my app

```
{
  "name": "my-config",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm run co:login",
    "co:login": "aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository my-repo --domain my-domain --domain-owner <123456789> --profile <me>",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "@my-npm/my-common": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

step 2: I configure multi repository in my .npmrc file using @scope:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
@my-npm:registry=https://my-domain-<123456789>.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/npm/my-repo/
```

step 3: run `npm install`